# crear background image con css

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer el cabecero de mi pagina web pero la propiedad `background-size` no me cubre todo el espacio que deseo ya intente de varias formas.

Código:

```css
.contabilidad{
    background-image: url(../../assets/Contabilidad.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 400px;
}
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Hola @Christopher. Si funciona tu código. Este tipo de problemas suelen ocurrir cuando hay una regla CSS interfiriendo en tu elemento HTML; en este caso, la anchura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera puedes obtener que tu imagen ocupe el ancho de la página y que sigas manteniendo tu texto en la forma como la tenías. Te dejo el ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .contabilidad {
            background-image: url(../../assets/Contabilidad.jpeg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            height: 400px;
            border-top: 5px solid green;
        }

        .contabilidad > img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .texto {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 3rem;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Contabilidad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contabilidad">
        <p class="texto">Hola</p>
        <img src="contabilidad.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```